# Changed an input field from required to not-required but it is still required

Tags: custom-field

I have created a custom Number field and set it as required. I later changed that field to not-required. But Users are reporting that the field is still required, even though when checking the Object Schema it is *not* marked as required.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

We are using Lightning.

Comment: Have you checked Page Layouts, you can specify fields as Required there too?

Comment: @ytiq Yes, this was it! Thank you! If you'd answer the question as an Answer I can mark you as correct.

Comment: Thanks, added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Page Layouts, you can specify fields as Required there too.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked Is there any validation rules on that particular field
Check if that field is referneced in any triggers